# Google Web Fonts not working for IE < 9

Tags: css, font-face, google-webfonts

I notice Google Web Fonts does not seem to work for IE < 9. How can I fix this?

Comment: Google Web Fonts are supported in IE6+, what behaviour do you obeserve?

Comment: Google web fonts appears to not be working. It seems to have started this morning. I can not get them to work in anything.

Answer (score 17):

They seem to be working fine for me.

One thing to keep in mind is if you're viewing the page locally Google Web Fonts will not load. You have to preview your page off of a server.

i.e.

> localhost/project/index.html = good
>     C:\Project\index.html = bad

Comment: I had the same issue. This was solid answer for it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question doesn't contain any actual information it's impossible to answer.

However, for reference to other Googlers, I can inform that Google will refuse to deliver any contents in the css file if you request more than 6 fonts using IE7 or IE8, instead it will say:

```
/*
 * Please request fewer web fonts for Internet Explorer or only the fonts which are used on this page.
 * Internet Explorer blocks and downloads ALL requested web fonts, whether they are used or not.
 * 
 * Requested web fonts: family=Ubuntu|Quicksand|Ewert|Condiment|Asap|Glegoo|Alike
 * 
 * We welcome feedback on our "moderator page" available at http://code.google.com/webfonts
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a document type declaration issue